# Capybara/Poltergeist failed to reach server (Connection refused + GET '/identify')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, poltergeist

#### Update

- `test.log` is showing that the server is responding to our test and rendering the page.
- Poltergeist fails with `Capybara::Poltergeist::StatusFailError: Request to 'http://127.0.0.1:50712/computers' failed to reach server, check DNS and/or server status - Timed out with no open resource requests`.

---

Poltergeist is unable to connect to the server.

I have tried **many** variations, including:

- Longer timeout periods (up to 300 seconds).
- Setting the Capybara.app_host to www.example.com, localhost, or 127.0.0.1.
- Removing phantomjs_options.
- Removing `force_ssl if: :ssl_configured?` from `static_controller.rb`.
- Rendering `users/sign_in` with no layout to eliminate external javascript.
- Changing the test to call `new_user_session_path`, `new_user_session_url`, and `/users/sign_in`.
- Running `RAILS_ENV=test rake assets:precompile` before running the test (manually).

When I run `rails s -e test`, I can open the URL `127.0.0.1:3000/users/sign_in`.

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
✗ RAILS_ENV="test" ruby -I test test/integration/computers_test.rb -n /polt/
Started with run options -n /polt/ --seed 10197

http://www.example.com/
*** Capybara current_driver: poltergeist=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---] 0% Time: 00:00:00,  ETA: ??:??:??
{"id":"2706e68d-1997-4272-8a5c-ce4f0e1c8416","name":"set_js_errors","args":[false]}
2017-05-12T15:28:10 [DEBUG] CookieJar - Created but will not store cookies (use option '--cookies-file=<filename>' to enable persistent cookie storage)
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG] Set  "http"  proxy to:  "" : 1080
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG] Phantom - execute: Configuration
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG]      0 objectName : ""
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG]      1 cookiesFile : ""
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG]      2 diskCacheEnabled : "false"
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG]      3 maxDiskCacheSize : "-1"
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG]      4 diskCachePath : ""
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG]      5 ignoreSslErrors : "true"
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG]      6 localUrlAccessEnabled : "true"
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG]      7 localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled : "false"
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG]      8 outputEncoding : "UTF-8"
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG]      9 proxyType : "http"
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG]      10 proxy : ":1080"
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG]      11 proxyAuth : ":"
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG]      12 scriptEncoding : "UTF-8"
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG]      13 webSecurityEnabled : "true"
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG]      14 offlineStoragePath : ""
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG]      15 localStoragePath : ""
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG]      16 localStorageDefaultQuota : "-1"
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG]      17 offlineStorageDefaultQuota : "-1"
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG]      18 printDebugMessages : "true"
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG]      19 javascriptCanOpenWindows : "true"
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG]      20 javascriptCanCloseWindows : "true"
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG]      21 sslProtocol : "tlsv1"
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG]      22 sslCiphers : "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:RC4-SHA:RC4-MD5"
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG]      23 sslCertificatesPath : ""
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG]      24 sslClientCertificateFile : ""
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG]      25 sslClientKeyFile : ""
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG]      26 sslClientKeyPassphrase : ""
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG]      27 webdriver : ":"
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG]      28 webdriverLogFile : ""
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG]      29 webdriverLogLevel : "INFO"
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG]      30 webdriverSeleniumGridHub : ""
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG] Phantom - execute: Script & Arguments
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG]      script: "/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/poltergeist-1.15.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/client/compiled/main.js"
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG]      0 arg: "53807"
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG]      1 arg: "1024"
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG]      2 arg: "768"
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG]      3 arg: "127.0.0.1"
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG] Phantom - execute: Starting normal mode
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG] WebPage - setupFrame ""
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/fs.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r")))
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/system.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r")))
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/webpage.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r")))
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG] Phantom - injectJs: "/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/poltergeist-1.15.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/client/compiled/web_page.js"
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG] Phantom - injectJs: "/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/poltergeist-1.15.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/client/compiled/node.js"
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG] Phantom - injectJs: "/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/poltergeist-1.15.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/client/compiled/connection.js"
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG] Phantom - injectJs: "/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/poltergeist-1.15.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/client/compiled/cmd.js"
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG] Phantom - injectJs: "/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/poltergeist-1.15.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/client/compiled/browser.js"
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG] WebpageCallbacks - getJsConfirmCallback
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG] WebpageCallbacks - getJsConfirmCallback
{"command_id":"2706e68d-1997-4272-8a5c-ce4f0e1c8416","response":true}
{"id":"04d6228c-1e9f-4f09-b93c-54bde8cf8396","name":"set_debug","args":[true]}
{"command_id":"04d6228c-1e9f-4f09-b93c-54bde8cf8396","response":true}
{"id":"937c83cc-33af-41d0-a6b3-3d01ec5b0d7d","name":"visit","args":["http://127.0.0.1/users/sign_in"]}
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 10
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG] Network - Resource request error: QNetworkReply::NetworkError(ConnectionRefusedError) ( "Connection refused" ) URL: "http://127.0.0.1/users/sign_in"
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 100
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG] WebPage - setupFrame ""
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG] WebPage - setupFrame ""
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG] WebPage - evaluateJavaScript "(function() { return (function () {\n      return typeof __poltergeist;\n    })(); })()"
2017-05-12T15:28:11 [DEBUG] WebPage - evaluateJavaScript result QVariant(QString, "undefined")
{"command_id":"937c83cc-33af-41d0-a6b3-3d01ec5b0d7d","error":{"name":"Poltergeist.StatusFailError","args":["http://127.0.0.1/users/sign_in",null]}}
ERROR["test_basic_poltergeist_test", ComputersTest, 1.0828739999997197]
 test_basic_poltergeist_test#ComputersTest (1.08s)
Capybara::Poltergeist::StatusFailError:         Capybara::Poltergeist::StatusFailError: Request to 'http://127.0.0.1/users/sign_in' failed to reach server, check DNS and/or server status
            poltergeist (1.15.0) lib/capybara/poltergeist/browser.rb:377:in `command'
            poltergeist (1.15.0) lib/capybara/poltergeist/browser.rb:36:in `visit'
            poltergeist (1.15.0) lib/capybara/poltergeist/driver.rb:97:in `visit'
            capybara (2.14.0) lib/capybara/session.rb:269:in `visit'
            capybara (2.14.0) lib/capybara/dsl.rb:50:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
            test/integration/computers_test.rb:43:in `block in <class:ComputersTest>'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest/test.rb:107:in `block (3 levels) in run'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest/test.rb:204:in `capture_exceptions'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest/test.rb:104:in `block (2 levels) in run'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest/test.rb:255:in `time_it'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest/test.rb:103:in `block in run'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:348:in `on_signal'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest/test.rb:275:in `with_info_handler'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest/test.rb:102:in `run'
            minitest-reporters (1.1.14) lib/minitest/reporters.rb:48:in `run_with_hooks'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:799:in `run_one_method'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:322:in `run_one_method'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:310:in `block (2 levels) in run'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:309:in `each'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:309:in `block in run'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:348:in `on_signal'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:335:in `with_info_handler'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:308:in `run'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:158:in `block in __run'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:158:in `map'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:158:in `__run'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:135:in `run'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:62:in `block in autorun'

  1/1: [=========================================================================================================================================================] 100% Time: 00:00:01, Time: 00:00:01

Finished in 1.08368s
1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

computers_test.rb

```
require "test_helper"
include Warden::Test::Helpers

class ComputersTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    @user = users(:one)
  end

  test "basic poltergeist test" do
    Capybara.default_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver

    visit '/users/sign_in'
    puts page.html
  end
end
```

test_helper.rb

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require 'capybara/rails'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :all
  require 'minitest/reporters'    # Better feedback when running tests.
  Minitest::Reporters.use!
  Capybara.default_driver = :rack_test
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
  include Warden::Test::Helpers   # Help with logging in and out.
end

class ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::TestHelpers
end

class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Capybara::DSL

  require 'capybara/poltergeist'
  Capybara.register_driver(:poltergeist) do |app|
    Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, {
      js_errors: false,
      debug: true,
      inspector: true,
      timeout: 45,
      stdout: true,
      phantomjs_options: ['--load-images=no', '--ignore-ssl-errors=yes', '--ssl-protocol=TLSv1', '--debug=true'],
      url_whitelist: ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost', 'example.com']
    })
  end
end

Capybara.server_port = 3000
Capybara.app_host = Capybara.default_host = "http://127.0.0.1"
```

The server logs when I run a test (this block happens twice):

```
[2017-05-12 16:05:49] ERROR ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET] "/__identify__"
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:39:in `call'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.7/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.7/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.7/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.7/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in `call'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rack-cors-0.4.0/lib/rack/cors.rb:80:in `call'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
    /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
    /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
    /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
    /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:296:in `block in start_thread'
```

---

New logs after:

- Switching to Puma
- Adding in the code for Minitest
- Setting `Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist` in test_helper.rb to stop running rack_test by mistake.
- Removing `Capybara.default_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver` from the test.

Logs:

```
✗ RAILS_ENV="test" ruby -I test test/integration/computers_test.rb -n /polt/
Started with run options -n /polt/ --seed 62956

http://www.example.com/*** Capybara current_driver: poltergeist=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---] 0% Time: 00:00:00,  ETA: ??:??:??
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.8.2 (ruby 2.3.1-p112), codename: Sassy Salamander
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 4
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:50003
Use Ctrl-C to stop
{"id":"5d4ede2b-395f-4960-84d3-f963f8b470ac","name":"set_js_errors","args":[false]}
2017-05-12T18:03:43 [DEBUG] CookieJar - Created but will not store cookies (use option '--cookies-file=<filename>' to enable persistent cookie storage)
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG] Set  "http"  proxy to:  "" : 1080
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG] Phantom - execute: Configuration
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG]      0 objectName : ""
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG]      1 cookiesFile : ""
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG]      2 diskCacheEnabled : "false"
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG]      3 maxDiskCacheSize : "-1"
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG]      4 diskCachePath : ""
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG]      5 ignoreSslErrors : "true"
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG]      6 localUrlAccessEnabled : "true"
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG]      7 localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled : "false"
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG]      8 outputEncoding : "UTF-8"
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG]      9 proxyType : "http"
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG]      10 proxy : ":1080"
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG]      11 proxyAuth : ":"
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG]      12 scriptEncoding : "UTF-8"
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG]      13 webSecurityEnabled : "true"
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG]      14 offlineStoragePath : ""
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG]      15 localStoragePath : ""
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG]      16 localStorageDefaultQuota : "-1"
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG]      17 offlineStorageDefaultQuota : "-1"
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG]      18 printDebugMessages : "true"
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG]      19 javascriptCanOpenWindows : "true"
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG]      20 javascriptCanCloseWindows : "true"
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG]      21 sslProtocol : "tlsv1"
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG]      22 sslCiphers : "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:RC4-SHA:RC4-MD5"
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG]      23 sslCertificatesPath : ""
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG]      24 sslClientCertificateFile : ""
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG]      25 sslClientKeyFile : ""
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG]      26 sslClientKeyPassphrase : ""
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG]      27 webdriver : ":"
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG]      28 webdriverLogFile : ""
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG]      29 webdriverLogLevel : "INFO"
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG]      30 webdriverSeleniumGridHub : ""
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG] Phantom - execute: Script & Arguments
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG]      script: "/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/poltergeist-1.15.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/client/compiled/main.js"
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG]      0 arg: "50007"
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG]      1 arg: "1024"
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG]      2 arg: "768"
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG]      3 arg: "127.0.0.1"
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG] Phantom - execute: Starting normal mode
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG] WebPage - setupFrame ""
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/fs.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r")))
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/system.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r")))
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/webpage.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r")))
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG] Phantom - injectJs: "/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/poltergeist-1.15.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/client/compiled/web_page.js"
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG] Phantom - injectJs: "/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/poltergeist-1.15.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/client/compiled/node.js"
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG] Phantom - injectJs: "/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/poltergeist-1.15.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/client/compiled/connection.js"
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG] Phantom - injectJs: "/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/poltergeist-1.15.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/client/compiled/cmd.js"
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG] Phantom - injectJs: "/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/poltergeist-1.15.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/client/compiled/browser.js"
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG] WebpageCallbacks - getJsConfirmCallback
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG] WebpageCallbacks - getJsConfirmCallback
{"command_id":"5d4ede2b-395f-4960-84d3-f963f8b470ac","response":true}
{"id":"916e1ab9-2d3e-4834-bed6-9fe1689ee267","name":"set_debug","args":[true]}
{"command_id":"916e1ab9-2d3e-4834-bed6-9fe1689ee267","response":true}
{"id":"1273bf4e-1a38-49fe-86ed-c598b7db0c46","name":"visit","args":["http://127.0.0.1:50003/computers"]}
2017-05-12T18:03:44 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 10
{"command_id":"1273bf4e-1a38-49fe-86ed-c598b7db0c46","error":{"name":"Poltergeist.StatusFailError","args":["http://127.0.0.1:50003/computers","Timed out with no open resource requests"]}}
{"id":"5436e5db-de6b-42cb-853c-98ef72f3e8cb","name":"reset","args":[]}
2017-05-12T18:04:04 [DEBUG] WebPage - evaluateJavaScript "(function() { return (function () {\n      return typeof __poltergeist;\n    })(); })()"
2017-05-12T18:04:04 [DEBUG] WebPage - setupFrame ""
2017-05-12T18:04:04 [DEBUG] WebPage - evaluateJavaScript "(function() { return (function () {\n      return typeof __poltergeist;\n    })(); })()"
2017-05-12T18:04:04 [DEBUG] WebPage - evaluateJavaScript result QVariant(QString, "undefined")
2017-05-12T18:04:04 [DEBUG] WebPage - evaluateJavaScript result QVariant(QString, "object")
2017-05-12T18:04:04 [DEBUG] WebPage - evaluateJavaScript "(function() { return (function() { var page_id = arguments[0]; var args = []; for(var i=1; i < arguments.length; i++){ if ((typeof(arguments[i]) == 'object') && (typeof(arguments[i]['ELEMENT']) == 'object')){ args.push(window.__poltergeist.get(arguments[i]['ELEMENT']['id']).element); } else { args.push(arguments[i]) } } var _result = (function (name, args) {\n      return __poltergeist.externalCall(name, args);\n    }).apply(this, args); return window.__poltergeist.wrapResults(_result, page_id); })(1,\"currentUrl\",[]); })()"
2017-05-12T18:04:04 [DEBUG] WebPage - evaluateJavaScript result QVariant(QVariantMap, QMap(("value", QVariant(QString, "about:blank"))))
2017-05-12T18:04:04 [DEBUG] WebpageCallbacks - getJsConfirmCallback
2017-05-12T18:04:04 [DEBUG] WebpageCallbacks - getJsConfirmCallback
2017-05-12T18:04:04 [DEBUG] Network - Resource request error: QNetworkReply::NetworkError(OperationCanceledError) ( "Operation canceled" ) URL: "http://127.0.0.1:50003/computers"
{"command_id":"5436e5db-de6b-42cb-853c-98ef72f3e8cb","response":true}
ERROR["test_basic_poltergeist_test", ComputersTest, 81.278547]
 test_basic_poltergeist_test#ComputersTest (81.28s)
Capybara::Poltergeist::StatusFailError:         Capybara::Poltergeist::StatusFailError: Request to 'http://127.0.0.1:50003/computers' failed to reach server, check DNS and/or server status - Timed out with no open resource requests
            poltergeist (1.15.0) lib/capybara/poltergeist/browser.rb:377:in `command'
            poltergeist (1.15.0) lib/capybara/poltergeist/browser.rb:36:in `visit'
            poltergeist (1.15.0) lib/capybara/poltergeist/driver.rb:97:in `visit'
            capybara (2.14.0) lib/capybara/session.rb:269:in `visit'
            capybara (2.14.0) lib/capybara/dsl.rb:50:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
            test/integration/computers_test.rb:43:in `block in <class:ComputersTest>'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest/test.rb:107:in `block (3 levels) in run'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest/test.rb:204:in `capture_exceptions'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest/test.rb:104:in `block (2 levels) in run'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest/test.rb:255:in `time_it'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest/test.rb:103:in `block in run'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:348:in `on_signal'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest/test.rb:275:in `with_info_handler'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest/test.rb:102:in `run'
            minitest-reporters (1.1.14) lib/minitest/reporters.rb:48:in `run_with_hooks'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:799:in `run_one_method'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:322:in `run_one_method'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:310:in `block (2 levels) in run'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:309:in `each'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:309:in `block in run'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:348:in `on_signal'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:335:in `with_info_handler'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:308:in `run'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:158:in `block in __run'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:158:in `map'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:158:in `__run'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:135:in `run'
            minitest (5.9.0) lib/minitest.rb:62:in `block in autorun'

  1/1: [=========================================================================================================================================================] 100% Time: 00:01:21, Time: 00:01:21

Finished in 81.31869s
1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

---

Latest test.log

```
------------------------------------------
ComputersTest: test_basic_poltergeist_test
------------------------------------------
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 980190962]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  [1m[36mUser Exists (0.4ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" = 'jb@test.com' AND "users"."id" != 980190962) LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.2ms)[0m  UPDATE "users" SET "role" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = $3  [["role", "admin"], ["updated_at", "2017-05-12 22:56:37.823070"], ["id", 980190962]]
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mRELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 980190962]]
  [1m[35mComputer Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT  "computers".* FROM "computers" WHERE "computers"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 169251709]]
Started GET "/computers" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-05-12 18:56:38 -0400
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  BEGIN
  [1m[35mSQL (180058.1ms)[0m  UPDATE "users" SET "last_sign_in_at" = $1, ...  [...]
  [1m[36m (0.3ms)[0m  [1mROLLBACK[0m
  [1m[36m (1.0ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
Processing by ComputersController#index as HTML
  [1m[36mComputer Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "computers".* FROM "computers" WHERE "computers"."company_id" = $1 AND "computers"."company_id" = $2[0m  [["company_id", 980190962], ["company_id", 980190962]]
  [1m[35mComputer Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT "computers".* FROM "computers" WHERE "computers"."company_id" = $1 AND "computers"."company_id" = $2 AND (project_id IS NULL OR project_id IN (980190962,298486374,198381282))  [["company_id", 980190962], ["company_id", 980190962]]
  Rendered shared/_searchBox.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered computers/index.html.erb within layouts/application (7.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_google_analytics.js.erb (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 99ms (Views: 49.8ms | ActiveRecord: 27.3ms)
```

Updated readout when running the test:

```
✗ RAILS_ENV="test" ruby -I test test/integration/computers_test.rb -n /polt/
Started with run options -n /polt/ --seed 20863

http://www.example.com/*** Capybara current_driver: poltergeist=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---=---] 0% Time: 00:00:00,  ETA: ??:??:??
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.8.2 (ruby 2.3.1-p112), codename: Sassy Salamander
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 4
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:50712
Use Ctrl-C to stop
{"id":"17f0e808-0a24-4d7a-90ce-d36fa5fd7092","name":"set_js_errors","args":[false]}
2017-05-12T18:56:38 [DEBUG] CookieJar - Created but will not store cookies (use option '--cookies-file=<filename>' to enable persistent cookie storage)
...
2017-05-12T18:58:38 [DEBUG] Network - Resource request error: QNetworkReply::NetworkError(OperationCanceledError) ( "Operation canceled" ) URL: "http://127.0.0.1:50712/computers"
{"command_id":"75aada14-e9bf-4bba-b125-72de33da1fad","response":true}
{"id":"2bc940aa-359c-4148-9007-27e1553c3e86","name":"set_url_whitelist","args":["127.0.0.1","localhost","example.com"]}
{"command_id":"2bc940aa-359c-4148-9007-27e1553c3e86","response":true}
ERROR["test_basic_poltergeist_test", ComputersTest, 181.03450100000055]
 test_basic_poltergeist_test#ComputersTest (181.03s)
Capybara::Poltergeist::StatusFailError:         Capybara::Poltergeist::StatusFailError: Request to 'http://127.0.0.1:50712/computers' failed to reach server, check DNS and/or server status - Timed out with no open resource requests
            poltergeist (1.15.0) lib/capybara/poltergeist/browser.rb:377:in `command'
...

  1/1: [=========================================================================================================================================================] 100% Time: 00:03:01, Time: 00:03:01

Finished in 181.03610s
1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that it shows an attempted visit to "http://127.0.0.1/users/sign_in" tells you there is a configuration error somewhere because there should be a port number in there (Capybara never runs its tests on port 80).

First, you've set `Capybara.server_port = 3000`.  Do you have a need for that rather than letting Capybara assign a random free port?  If you do need it fixed, 3000 is a bad choice since that will prevent you from having your dev instance running while tests run.

Second, you've set `Capybara.app_host`.  Do you have a real need for setting this?  It's generally used when you want to test against an external site, or if you have special IP requirements.  If you really have a need for setting `app_host` you probably also need to set `Capybara.always_include_port = true`

So two solutions

1. Get rid of setting `app_host` and `server_port` and just let Capybara manage them
2. Change your fixed server port to something other than 3000 and add `Capybara.always_include_port = true`

Additionally you probably want to read https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#using-capybara-with-minitest because setting `Capybara.default_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver` inside your test isn't going to do what you want.

Comment: I just ran the same test without `app_host` or `server_port`. It gets stuck on: `{"id":"7be3880d-5c48-44ab-b2ad-7ee716579a0e","name":"visit","args":["http://127.0.0.1:51044/users/sign_in"]}
2017-05-12T16:58:28 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 10`

Comment: @sscirrus . Check your test.log and make you sure you don't have debugging statements (byebug/binding.pry/etc) leftover in your code

Comment: @sscirrus  Oh - and if your app is making web requests to it's own API internally make sure you've set `Capybara.server = :puma` so it can handle multiple concurrent requests.  The first request may also take a while if rails has to build the assets

Comment: Something just worked... I'll check it out properly and get back to you!

Comment: It worked because I got rid of `Capybara.default_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver`, and that ended up using rack_test. When I set `Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist`, I'm now getting `'Operation canceled'` when it tries to access `"http://127.0.0.1:50003/computers"`.

Comment: @sscirrus Add the logs or better yet create a new question on SO -- you're now hitting the Capybara server and making requests which is what this question was about.

Comment: I added logs. Unfortunately it is still not getting to the server. I'm getting `failed to reach server, check DNS and/or server status` as I've gotten before.

Comment: Where is that URL coming from? It doesn't match your test at all? and set your timeout to at least 120.  Also what does your test.log show?

Comment: The URL is expected - just a different page I tried. Timeout set to 120. test.log sticks at `2017-05-12T18:48:25 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 10` for a while, then fails with: `"error":{"name":"Poltergeist.StatusFailError","args":["http://127.0.0.1:50589/computers","Timed out with no open resource requests"]}}`.

Comment: @sscirrus that's not the rails test.log, look in your apps log directory

Comment: Of course, apologies. It goes from waiting at `Started GET "/computers" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-05-12 18:56:38 -0400
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  BEGIN` to `[1m[35mSQL (180058.1ms)[0m  UPDATE "users" SET ...]
  [1m[36m (0.3ms)[0m  [1mROLLBACK[0m
  [1m[36m (1.0ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
Processing by ComputersController#index as HTML`. It appears that the server thinks it's rendering (it ends with `Completed 200 OK in 99ms`.

Comment: @sscirrus Ok - so the request is making it to the app.  Not sure why it's rolling back inside the request though, seems like your controller may have some issue.  Is that 99ms for that specific request, or for a different request? If you added the full relevant log sections to the question it would be easier.

Comment: I just added `test.log` and the readout from the server at the bottom of the question.

Comment: @sscirrus Not sure what's going on with your app, but it looks like you have multiple requests hitting it at the same time somehow -  The `SQL (180058.1ms)[0m  UPDATE "users" SET` line shows a SQL command taking 180 seconds right in the middle of the other request - no DB request should be taking that long in tests unless you have other things hitting the same database (shouldn't be in test) and locking it.   Are you using a real database for this or are you using SQLite?  The abbreviated logs also don't help determine whats actually going on.

Comment: @sscirrus Also what's with the id numbers in your test database being so large? Are you not clearing out the database between test runs?  Might as well add the actual test you're running too, so we can see what exactly you're doing.

Comment: I checked the IDs - there aren't more than ten of any record in my test DB. My test DB (Postgres) is creating new records with large-number IDs.

Comment: The actual test is nothing special. Just: `test "basic poltergeist test" do; visit computers_path; puts page.html[0..250]; end;`.

Comment: To your first question about the 180058.1ms: I'm using Postgres and nothing else is calling the test server to my knowledge. I quit and restarted the test server to be sure -> no difference. I then opened `rails c -e test` and updated a user - that happened quickly

Comment: OK we're making progress. The system is failing in the test's *setup* at this part: `@user.role = "admin"; @user.save; @user.reload`. The saving is what's causing the failure.
This may be unrelated, but when the test begins, it says 'Puma starting in single mode... Environment: development'. Shouldn't it say test?

Comment: @sscirrus Yes it should be starting in the test environment

Comment: In that case, I'm guessing that if I can get it to do that, it might access the right DB and not timeout when trying to update the record. I'll post a separate question. I'll get back to you on this as soon as I figure out how to configure Puma to start in the test environment.

Comment: Hi Thomas - the server is still starting in development and I haven't been able to change a record manually in my test (`@user.role = "admin"; @user.save`), but the basics of Capybara and Poltergeist appear to be working. I posted separately on those issues. Thank you so very much. Accepted and +1.

Answer (score 0):

I was having exactly the same issue/symptoms as OP when upgrading from Rails 4.2 to Rails 5.0. I finally figured it out from noticing that the database time was so long - transactional fixtures were enabled, when they should have been disabled. I'm not sure what changed to cause this default flip, but by more explicitly disabling transactional fixtures I was able to fix the issue.